# Error when trying to show tables content from the staging server(Azure) via SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssms-2012

I am connected to a remote Microsoft Azure server via SQL Server Management Studio. The problem I am facing is that I am not getting an option to "Select Top 1000 rows" of a table (screenshot attached). What I am doing wrong? I am using SSMS2012. Regards.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not wrong.

I tested using SSMS 2012 and have the same problem with you.

But, When i use SSMS 2017, i can get the option of "Select Top 1000 rows".

So we just need to update our SSMS to the latest version.

We can download the latest version of SSMS at: [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

In addition, we can also execute T-SQL directly: `select top (1000) * from [TableName]`

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. When I connect via the latest version of VS, I am getting the same thing. Thanks.